# How can I install lib_mysqludf_sys on linux?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

I have been looking for running a python script as a trigger on table insertion. I found that I needed to use something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Test_Trigger
AFTER INSERT ON SFCRoutingTable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE cmd CHAR(255);
DECLARE result int(10);
SET cmd = CONCAT('python /home/triggers.py');
SET result = sys_exec(cmd);
END;
```

That trigger should work after insertion, but I get an error which is 'FUNCTION db.sys_exec does not exist'. I found that I need to install a plugin since that is not a standard MySQL library.

I think I need to install this [library](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys#readme) but I'm not really sure how to do that since I run into a lot of errors.

Comment: I think it's usually a bad idea to run external code in a trigger. Keep in mind that the action that spawned the trigger might be rolled back. But whatever your python script does will not be rolled back. If it does something like notify you that new data has been inserted, you might go check and find no new data. Either it's rolled back, or else not committed yet when you check.

Comment: That's such a great point Bill. I thought about running an external code only to take a further processing on the row that has been committed. I have read through the internet and found that I'm better to not save binary files in the database so I thought that I would save them temporarily on the database and the external script would extract the data on the server and delete it from the database after

Comment: there were a lot of security risks involved with that library, so you shouldn't install it but see http://mysql-ninjas.blogspot.com/2019/08/shellbash-commands-execution-from-mysql.html

Comment: Okay, if you intend the python script to read the data inserted, then by definition it cannot read it, because it won't be committed yet and therefore a new MySQL connection created in your python script can't "see" it. This doesn't have to be this complicated. If you want the file saved to disk, just do that in your client application, _instead of_ inserting it to the database.